# How do I train a Botonic project with NLP?

Tags: chatbot, training-data

I'm currently trying to build a chatbot using Botonic and trying to integrate NLP.
I'm following the instructions offered by the official user guide.  The folder structure that I get after creating new Botonic project is different from the one they are indicating in the documents: I get:

```
src/nlp/data
src/nlp/tasks/intent-classification/models
src/nlp/tasks/intent-classification/train.ts
```

while in the documents it's written that I should find this structure:

src/nlu/utterances/en

containing utterances related to an intent.
Now I'm trying to train my bot; in file package.json, I find:

```
`"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --env target=all --mode=production",
    "start": "webpack serve --env target=dev --mode=development",
    "test": "jest",
    "train:ner": "ts-node src/nlp/tasks/ner/train.ts",
    "train:intent-classification": "ts-node src/nlp/tasks/intent-classification/train.ts"
  },`
```

**which prevents me from training my Botonic project, because I don't have that folder structure. Shall I create a new folder under tasks? And what shall I put in train.ts under it?**

I get this error :

```
`child process exited with code 0C:\Users\...\...\....\....\....\testBot\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\index.js:49
    throw new Error("The Node.js native addon module (tfjs_binding.node) can not " +
          ^
Error: The Node.js native addon module (tfjs_binding.node) can not be found at path: C:\Users\...\...\....\....\....\testBot\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v7\tfjs_binding.node.
Please run command 'npm rebuild @tensorflow/tfjs-node build-addon-from-source' to rebuild the native addon module.
If you have problem with building the addon module, please check https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/blob/master/tfjs-node/WINDOWS_TROUBLESHOOTING.md or file an issue.
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\...\....\....\....\testBot\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\dist\index.js:49:11)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (C:\Users\...\...\....\....\....\testBot\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1608:43)    
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\...\....\....\....\testBot\node_modules\@botonic\nlp\src\embeddings\embeddings-matrix.ts:1:1)       
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
child process exited with code 1`
```

The problem persists even when I run `npm rebuild @tensorflow/tfjs-node build-addon-from-source`.